# xmms2 widget for awesome

Tags: awesome, xmms2

I am trying to use the [xmms2 widget](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Xmms2_Widgets).  As it is, the widget does not conforms to awesome 3.X specifications -- or at least, I may have misunderstood how widgets should work.  I certainly cannot get it to display anything as is.

Does anyone have an update to this widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a widget as such but you can get keyboard short cuts by adding

```
awful.key({}, "XF86AudioPlay", function () awful.util.spawn_with_shell("nyxmms2 toggle") end),
awful.key({}, "XF86AudioStop", function () awful.util.spawn_with_shell("nyxmms2 stop") end),
awful.key({}, "XF86AudioPrev", function () awful.util.spawn_with_shell("nyxmms2 prev") end),
awful.key({}, "XF86AudioNext", function () awful.util.spawn_with_shell("nyxmms2 next") end)
```

to your `rc.lua` file.

In addition, the official site widget has been updated and the code there now works fine for me.